# Using $push with $group with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

### Objective

Fix my `make_pipeline()` function to, using an aggregation query, count the number of tweets for each user, add them to an array and return the 5 users with the most tweets.

### Exercise

Using an aggregation query, count the number of tweets for each user. 
In the same `$group` stage, use `$push` to accumulate all the tweet texts for each user.

Limit your output to the 5 users with the most tweets.

Your result documents should include only the fields:

- `"_id"` (screen name of user),
- `"count"` (number of tweets found for the user),
- `"tweet_texts"` (a list of the tweet texts found for the user).

### Background

To achieve the previous objective I am testing the following code:

```
def make_pipeline():
    # complete the aggregation pipeline
    pipeline = [
        {"$group": {"_id": "$user.screen_name", "tweet_texts": {"$push": "$text"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
        {"$project": {"_id": "$user.screen_name", "count": 1, "tweet_texts": 1}},
        {"$sort" : {"count" : -1}},
        {"$limit": 5}
    ]
    return pipeline
```

### Logic

First I group all the tweets by `username`. Then, in the same stage, I push all the texted tweets to `tweet_texts` and I count each occurrence that was grouped. I believe this will give me the number of users with most tweets.

Then I make a projection to select only the three fields I want:

- _id
- count
- tweet_texts

I finish by sorting and limiting the amount of results.

### Problem

I am passing the test, but not the submission. What am I doing wrong? 
I now the error must be in the first (group) stage, but I can't find for the love of God what I am doing wrong.

### Data Sample

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5304e2e3cc9e684aa98bef97"),
    "text" : "First week of school is over :P",
    "in_reply_to_status_id" : null,
    "retweet_count" : null,
    "contributors" : null,
    "created_at" : "Thu Sep 02 18:11:25 +0000 2010",
    "geo" : null,
    "source" : "web",
    "coordinates" : null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name" : null,
    "truncated" : false,
    "entities" : {
        "user_mentions" : [ ],
        "urls" : [ ],
        "hashtags" : [ ]
    },
    "retweeted" : false,
    "place" : null,
    "user" : {
        "friends_count" : 145,
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color" : "E5507E",
        "location" : "Ireland :)",
        "verified" : false,
        "follow_request_sent" : null,
        "favourites_count" : 1,
        "profile_sidebar_border_color" : "CC3366",
        "profile_image_url" : "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1107778717/phpkHoxzmAM_normal.jpg",
        "geo_enabled" : false,
        "created_at" : "Sun May 03 19:51:04 +0000 2009",
        "description" : "",
        "time_zone" : null,
        "url" : null,
        "screen_name" : "Catherinemull",
        "notifications" : null,
        "profile_background_color" : "FF6699",
        "listed_count" : 77,
        "lang" : "en",
        "profile_background_image_url" : "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_background_images/138228501/149174881-8cd806890274b828ed56598091c84e71_4c6fd4d8-full.jpg",
        "statuses_count" : 2475,
        "following" : null,
        "profile_text_color" : "362720",
        "protected" : false,
        "show_all_inline_media" : false,
        "profile_background_tile" : true,
        "name" : "Catherine Mullane",
        "contributors_enabled" : false,
        "profile_link_color" : "B40B43",
        "followers_count" : 169,
        "id" : 37486277,
        "profile_use_background_image" : true,
        "utc_offset" : null
    },
    "favorited" : false,
    "in_reply_to_user_id" : null,
    "id" : NumberLong("22819398300")
}
```

Please help!

Comment: I still dont understand the error. where do you get the error again ?

Comment: In your $project, shouldn't it be {"$project": {"_id": 1...}}?

Comment: Do you even need the project stage here?

Comment: There is no syntax error and the code doesn't blow up. It simply doesn't return the expected result. The user it is returning is not the one with the most tweets apparently. As for the $project, I believe I need it because the format of the answer only needs three fields and because I am renaming the _id field.

Comment: I tried with bunch of records the sorting n limiting seems to work fine.

Comment: If your requirement stipulates that you should only return just three fields then @SteveRossiter is correct, the `$group` pipeline already produces just those three fields so there's no need for a preceding `$project` stage. Besides, it's incorrect to `$project` the field `{ "_id": "$user.screen_name", ... }` since the previous `$group` pipeline doesn't produce any field `"$user.screen_name"`.

Comment: The correct pipeline should be `pipeline = [
        {"$group": {"_id": "$user.screen_name", "tweet_texts": {"$push": "$text"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},        
        {"$sort" : {"count" : -1}},
        {"$limit": 5}
    ]`

Comment: Will test it soon and let you know!

Comment: @chidram Hey, your solution worked ! Can you post it as an answer and explain me what my projection was doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reading comments

Reading the comments I found out that

```
pipeline = [
        {"$group": {"_id": "$user.screen_name", "tweet_texts": {"$push": "$text"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
        {"$project": {"_id": "$user.screen_name", "count": 1, "tweet_texts": 1}},
        {"$sort" : {"count" : -1}},
        {"$limit": 5}
    ]
```

Should in fact be changed to:

```
pipeline = [ 
        {"$group": {"_id": "$user.screen_name", "tweet_texts": {"$push": "$text"}, "count": {"$sum": 1}}}, 
        {"$sort" : {"count" : -1}}, 
        {"$limit": 5}
    ]
```

### Why?

The full answer and explanation can be seen in the answer:

- [What is the difference between these two MongoDB queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970583/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-mongodb-queries)

The conclusion of the story is that I am using the `$project` stage wrongly. Not only was is no needed in the first place, to make it idempotent it should be

```
{"$project": {"_id": "$_id", "count": 1, "tweet_texts": 1}},
```

I also highly recommend his answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40970901/1337392

### Special Thanks

The following users deserve kudos++:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/122005/chridam

For directing me in to the right path!

Answer (score 1):

The **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)** step is redundant as the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline already produces just those three fields so there's no need for a preceding **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)** stage.

The correct pipeline should be

```
pipeline = [ 
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$user.screen_name", 
            "tweet_texts": { "$push": "$text" }, 
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }, 
    { "$sort" : { "count" : -1 } }, 
    { "$limit": 5 } 
]
```

Your **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)** pipeline didn't work because the previous **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline doesn't produce any field `"$user.screen_name"` which you attempt to use as the `_id` field in the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)** pipeline.

However, if you wanted to include the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)** step then the working pipeline should follow:

```
pipeline = [ 
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$user.screen_name", 
            "tweet_texts": { "$push": "$text" }, 
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }, 
    { "$project": { "count": 1, "tweet_texts": 1 } },
    { "$sort" : { "count" : -1 } }, 
    { "$limit": 5 } 
]
```

Comment: You really had to post an answer just when I was about to post mine right? :P Anyway, kudos++

Comment: No worries :) I didn't get the notififications to explain the answer earlier because of the typo @chidram but it's all good now, happy you've found the solution.